# How to get SoftwareBitmap from MediaPlayer in UWP

Tags: c#, video, uwp

I am currently working on a project where I am receiving a live video stream from an IP camera as a MediaPlayer object. The end goal is to be able to use Windows.Media.OCR to extract text from a frame every second or so, and for this I need a SoftwareBitmap.

From the Microsoft UWP documentation, it appears that the frame can be taken from the MediaPlayer object with the method CopyFrameToVideoSurface(CanvasBitmap). I can create a CanvasBitmap *from* a SoftwareBitmap, but I have not found a way to create a SoftwareBitmap from the CanvasBitmap without having to save the file (which I am trying to avoid, I do not need to retain the images). I am hoping I am missing something simple, is there a way to get a SoftwareBitmap from a MediaPlayer object?

I have been referencing [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/play-audio-and-video-with-mediaplayer#use-mediaplayer-in-frame-server-mode) for using MediaPlayer in frame server mode. I do not need to display the image, so if possible it seems best to avoid the CanvasBitmap if I can.

**MediaPlayer**

```
private async Task GetStream()
{
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer()
    {
        Source = MediaSource.CreateFromStream(placeholder, "video")
    };

    mediaPlayer.VideoFrameAvailable += VideoFrameAvailable;
    mediaPlayer.IsVideoFrameServerEnabled = true;
    mediaPlayer.Play();
}

private async void VideoFrameAvailable(MediaPlayer sender, object args)
{
    // Get frame from media player, create SoftwareBitmap
    await ExtractText(softwareBitmapImg);
}
```

My code for the OCR portion is relatively simple and works like a charm when I have a SoftwareBitmap to provide.

**OCR**

```
private async Task ExtractText()
{
    Language ocrLanguage = new Language("en-us");
    OcrEngine ocrEngine = OcrEngine.TryCreateFromLanguage(ocrLanguage);

    var ocrResult = await ocrEngine.RecognizeAsync(bitmap);
    String text = ocrResult.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **CanvasBitmap** implement the [IDirect3DSurface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.directx.direct3d11.idirect3dsurface) interface, Whenever the **VideoFrameAvailable** handler is called, the [CopyFrameToVideoSurface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.playback.mediaplayer.copyframetovideosurface) method is used to copy the contents of the frame to an [IDirect3DSurface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.directx.direct3d11.idirect3dsurface). We need the **CanvasBitmap** object to copies the current frame from the MediaPlayer into the **CanvasBitmap** when the **CopyFrameToVideoSurface** is called, but you do not need to display the image.

```
private async void mediaPlayer_VideoFrameAvailable(MediaPlayer sender, object args)
{
    CanvasDevice canvasDevice = CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice();
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
    {
        SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmapImg;
        SoftwareBitmap frameServerDest = new SoftwareBitmap(BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8, 100, 100, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);

        using (CanvasBitmap canvasBitmap = CanvasBitmap.CreateFromSoftwareBitmap(canvasDevice, frameServerDest))
        {
            sender.CopyFrameToVideoSurface(canvasBitmap);

            softwareBitmapImg = await SoftwareBitmap.CreateCopyFromSurfaceAsync(canvasBitmap);

        }
        await ExtractText(softwareBitmapImg);
    });
}
```